# SQL How to correctly use the where operator in my query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There is a request for 15 minute intervals in the interval from 09.00 to 18.00 hours.

```
SELECT t.event_date,             
case                                                                         
  when TIME_TO_SEC(t.event_date) > inter.begin AND TIME_TO_SEC(t.event_date) < inter.end                           
  then floor((TIME_TO_SEC(t.event_date) - inter.begin) / inter.width)           

  when TIME_TO_SEC(t.event_date) <= inter.begin 
  then 0  

  when TIME_TO_SEC(t.event_date) >= inter.end 
  then floor((inter.end - inter.begin) / inter.width)  

  else null 

end as full_interval_number       
FROM table t,                     
    (select TIME_TO_SEC('09:00:00') as begin,  
            TIME_TO_SEC('18:00:00') as end,    
            TIME_TO_SEC('00:15:00') as width
     ) inter
```

How to use WHERE to exclude temporary intrevalues №0, 3, 7, 15 or intrevalues from 09.00 to 10.00 hours?

Something like this:

```
where
       TIME_TO_SEC(event_date) < TIME_TO_SEC('09:00:00') 
and TIME_TO_SEC(event_date) > TIME_TO_SEC('10:00:00')
```

or:

```
where
 full_interval_number not in (0, 3, 7, 15)
```

Comment: Is your query working as expected apart from the where clause? What is the exact problem with your suggested where clause's?

Comment: As in this query, use the where

Comment: I do not understand your reply.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? The first part is the general limit for 9-18 and the second part is the specific requirement to exclude values between 9-10

```
where TIME_TO_SEC(event_date) between TIME_TO_SEC('09:00:00') and TIME_TO_SEC('18:00:00')
and not (TIME_TO_SEC(event_date) between TIME_TO_SEC('09:00:00') and TIME_TO_SEC('10:00:00'))
```

Full query

```
SELECT t.event_date,             
case                                                                         
  when TIME_TO_SEC(t.event_date) > inter.begin AND TIME_TO_SEC(t.event_date) < inter.end                           
  then floor((TIME_TO_SEC(t.event_date) - inter.begin) / inter.width)           

  when TIME_TO_SEC(t.event_date) <= inter.begin 
  then 0  

  when TIME_TO_SEC(t.event_date) >= inter.end 
  then floor((inter.end - inter.begin) / inter.width)  

  else null 

end as full_interval_number       
FROM table t,                     
(select TIME_TO_SEC('09:00:00') as begin,  
        TIME_TO_SEC('18:00:00') as end,    
        TIME_TO_SEC('00:15:00') as width
 ) inter 
where TIME_TO_SEC(event_date) between TIME_TO_SEC('09:00:00') and TIME_TO_SEC('18:00:00')
and not (TIME_TO_SEC(event_date) between TIME_TO_SEC('09:00:00') and TIME_TO_SEC('10:00:00'))
```

Comment: exactly, but how do I use it in my query?

Comment: No, it will not work like this,  I tried. Correctly, my initial request to wrap in the "select * from ()", but how to do it I do not know.

Comment: Then you need to explain better in your question what it is that you want help with. You said that it was the where clause but if that is not it, then what is it?

Comment: @VikaSmirnova you still haven’t explained what you want.